# transform element and elements inside with XQuery

Tags: html, xml, xquery

I am a beginner to XQuery and I hope you can help me easily with my question. I have the following XML example:

```
<lg>
    <l n="1">Z nutz vnd heylsamer ler / verma⸗
    </l>
    <l n="2">nung vnd ervolgung der wyßheit / ver
    </l>
    <l n="3">nunfft vnd gter sytten : Ouch z ver⸗
    </l>
    <l n="4">achtung vnd straff der narheyt / blint⸗
    </l>
    <l n="5">heyt yrrsal vnd dorheit / aller stt / vnd
    </l>
    <l n="6">geschlecht der menschen : mit besun⸗
    </l>
    <l n="7">derem flyß ernst vnd arbeyt / gesamlet
    </l>
    <l n="8">z <ref target="narragonienLemmata.xml#basel">Basell</ref> : durch <ref target="narragonienLemmata.xml#brantSebastian">Sebastianum Brant</ref>.
    </l>
    <l n="9">in beyden rechten doctor.
    </l>
</lg>
```

What I am trying to do is to transform every line and put it into a HTML-div and at the same time, if there is a  inside the line, transform it into a HTML- element. My code right now puts the ref at the end of the block, of course, because I used a comma in between:

```
for $line in //lg//l, $lem in $line//ref
return
    element div{$line, element a{$lem}}
```

I just don't know how the construction works... thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Dominika

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your goal is to perform a transformation, one nice way to handle that is using a recursive `typeswitch` function. It is similar conceptually to XSLT but more explicit.

```
declare function local:transform($n)
{
  typeswitch($n)
  case element(lg) return <div>{
    for $child in $n/*
    return local:transform($child)
    }</div>
  case element(ref) return <a>{ $n/(@*|node()) }</a>
  case element() return element { node-name($n)} {
    for $child in $n/(@*|node())
    return local:transform($child)
  }
  default return $n
};
```

In the `typeswitch` you create an entry for each element or attribute name you wish to transform. In the `return` for each entry, you generate the element you want, and inside that element, direct the transform to recur on its child elements.

As you are building one of these functions, it is often helpful to include "identity" transformation entries. These will recursively copy everything that has not been defined explicitly. This is the identity portion of the `typeswitch`:

```
...
case element() return element { node-name($n)} {
  for $child in $n/(@*|node())
  return local:transform($child)
}
default return $n
...
```

Using this type of function, you can more easily maintain the structure of the original element, and focus on the explicit changes you want to make.

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me a lot... didn't know about this structure. Much appreciated. So basically afterwards I put all the stuff I want to transform into a variable and pass it to the function, right?

Comment: @dmnk.h Yes, assign the top-level element of the XML you want to transform to a variable, and pass that variable to the function.

Comment: @dmnk.h If this answer helped you solve your problem, please click the checkmark to the left to accept it!

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helpful!